# start node js server using cron job

Tags: node.js, api, cron, cron-task

I have created API using node js and my API is live now (in production) but now I always want to open Cpanel and terminal and run command to start node js API. but now I want like I just run one-time command in terminal and it will run automatically even in my computer is shutdown. or there is another way to do it. and I google it I found some code but it's not work
first, I try this

```
#!/bin/bash
ps cax | grep node > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "Process is running." >/dev/null 2>&1
else
  echo "Process is not running."
  PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
  pm2 start /path/to/your/node/application
fi
```

then i create bat file. and just simple add `node app.js` then i create php file and
use this code `shell_exec('npm start');` and `shell_exec('sh script.sh');` but nothing work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hello I Find This answer you just have install pm2 and run `pm2 startup` then run `pm2 save` to save your query.

for more information https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: @Harshith already answered it!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using pm2 to manage the node process, you can configure pm2 to auto restart the node process after you're computer restarts. refer below link to configure pm2

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/

Comment: Gowada but I want to run API even when my computer is shutdown.