# restart node app after app crash using nodemon

Tags: node.js, cron, web-hosting, nodemon

I am hosting a node js app on vps and I want to restart app if app crashed.
is it good to use `nodemon` instead of `node` for `start` in `package.json` file?
(performance and memory usage on production)

```js
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node db",
    "dev": "nodemon db"
  }
```

alternatively, is `pm2` suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63008268/start-node-js-server-using-cron-job) is good for both server crash and app crash?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using pm2 in production. It definitely handles crashes better than nodemon